# JMeter JMS Subscriber : How is the time taken by each sample is calculated?

Tags: jmeter

I have been using JMeter for quite sometime but this question hindering for sometime; For JMS Subscriber, How does the time taken by each sample is calculated? what's start time and what's end time? How is the time taken for the consecutive samples are calculated? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start time - the time when sampler started
- End time can be one of the following:

  - if there are no messages -  end time will be the time required to [MessageConsumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html) or [TopicSubscriber](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TopicSubscriber.html) to check for the new messages
  - if there are messages - end time will be the time required to fetch them all.
  - timeout occurs

More information: [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)

Comment: How about the time calculation for the messages after the first one? what's the start time for the 2nd message?

Comment: Accepting this answer even though it partially answered the question so that it helps others!